# Overwrite Colon() to concatenate head and tail

Tags: julia

Is it possible to overwrite `:` to allow this head and tail concatenation syntax?

```
julia> (:){T}(a::T, b::Array{T}) = vcat([a], b)                   
Colon()         

julia> a=collect(2:9);

julia> 1:a      
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching colon(::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1})
Closest candidates are:          
  colon(::T<:Real, ::Any, !Matched::T<:Real) where T<:Real at range.jl:47
  colon(::A<:Real, ::Any, !Matched::C<:Real) where {A<:Real, C<:Real} at range.jl:14
  colon(::T, ::Any, !Matched::T) where T at range.jl:46           
  ...
```

Comment: `expand(:(1:4))  #=> :(colon(1, 4))` which means the right function that should be overwritten is `colon`, not `:` or `Base.:(:)` and the error also gave you some clues about this. however, I don't think it's a good idea to overwrite colon, I guess `unshift!(a, 1)` is enough for most use cases?

Comment: Thank you. `colon` works perfectly! I thought `colon` and `:` were the same. You're right, overwrite range operator for a different meaning is confusing. I wish there is a `SuperArray` type (`view`) of two arrays as one array in julia, just as `SubArray` does.

Comment: something like [CatViews](https://github.com/ahwillia/CatViews.jl)?

Comment: `x = CatView(a,b);   # no copying!!!` it's fantastic. Thanks for pointing it out.